# How to write on first empty row through xlwings?

Tags: python

The excel file has content in `A1`, `A2` , `A3`. I want python to automatically write the output in first empty cell in column A .i.e it should write on `A4`

Another example - lets say if I have content written from `B1` to `B130`. Here I would like python to write the desired result in cell `B131`.

How do I form a python solution that can perform this task in excel through xlwings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your data is continuous, get the end of the current region to get the last cell then offset the cell by one to get the next empty cell.

```py
cel = Range("A1:A2")
rng = cel.current_region
last_cel=rng.end("down")
empty_cell= last_cel.offset(1,0)
```

now you can do what you want with the `empty_cell`

Comment: Thanks Gaurav but its only working for A column. I even changed cel = range("B1:B2") , even then its printing the output on A column only. Any reasons for this ?

Comment: can you show the screenshot of how your data is? the problem may be current_region property selecting multiple column even when you are applying it in B1:B2. If your cell in B is in same row as A, just offset this cell. Other solution would be special cells, VBA  & .NET has SpecialCells method to get empty cells, idk if xlwings has that.